# Replacing a string value with another string in entire Mongo collection using pymongo?

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I want to replace "-inf" with "NA" in my collection containing around 500 fields and ~10 million documents. The reason why I have mentioned string in my query is because I have changed the datatype of dataframe to string before saving in db.

Can someone please suggest an efficient solution to do so?

Comment: Do you know all the fields names that need changing? Do you want to change the fields matching `-inf` exactly or can `-inf` be contained in the string?

Comment: Exact match of -inf

Comment: Do you know all the fields names that need changing?

Comment: Not really..I need to search across 500 fields.

Answer (score 0):

Your choices are:

1. Program something that will iterate every record and then every field in that record, perform any updates and save them back into the database.
2. Export all the data in human readable format, performed a search-and-replace (using sed or similar), then load the data back in.

There's no magic command that will do what you want quickly and easily.

Comment: Currently, I have followed the following approach:
1. Iterate over each field and read data after filtering the value "-inf" from that field. (pymongo's find query)
2. If any such record found, set it's value to "NA". (pymongo's find_one_and_update query)

I was wondering if there is any better way to do so.